# Passing argument from incompatible pointer type (C)

Tags: c

I need to create a program that lists the hard-coded input into a different file. I have encountered issue in the fprintf section.

> The full program is listed in the back.

I have talked to my teacher and she marked

```
   else
    {
        print_rmchr(str1, chr1);
        print_rmchr(str2, chr2);
        print_rmchr(str3, chr3);
        print_rmchr(str4, chr4);
        print_rmchr(str5, chr5);

        if (fclose(filePtr) != 0)
            printf("Unable to close the data file.\n");
    }
```

and

```
if (fprintf("The string '%s' will be removed from '%c' characters. \n\n", str, ch) < 0)
    printf("Unable to print non-modified string with a modifying character. \n");

rmchr(str, ch);

if (fprintf("New modified string is: '%s'. \n\n", str) < 0)
    printf("Unable to print new modified string. \n");
```

as wrong part of the code in my assignment.

I looked at similar questions on starkoverflow and found that I have to put filepointer before fprintf.
My second chunk of the bad code now looks like this:

```
if (fprintf(filePtr, "The string '%s' will be removed from '%c' characters. \n\n", str, ch) < 0)
    printf("Unable to print non-modified string with a modifying character. \n");

rmchr(str, ch);

if (fprintf(filePtr, "New modified string is: '%s'. \n\n", str) < 0)
    printf("Unable to print new modified string. \n");
```

And then compiler yelled at me for not knowing why there was file pointer, so I also fixed it as

```
print_rmchr(filePtr, str, chr);
```

But then it began to yell at me as if "passing argument from incompatible pointer type". It looks right for me, but something is missing(?) I guess.

My full program:

```
/*
* A simple program to remove certain characters from the given strings                              
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    // print array before and after editing array
    void print_rmchr (char str[], char ch); 

    char str1[20] = "abracadabra";      //string #1
    char str2[20] = "abracadabra";      //string #2
    char str3[20] = "abracadabra";      //string #3
    char str4[20] = "aaaa";             //string #4
    char str5[20] = "aaaa";             //string #5

    char chr1 = 'a';                    //character #1
    char chr2 = 'b';                    //character #2
    char chr3 = 'n';                    //character #3
    char chr4 = 'a';                    //character #4
    char chr5 = 'n';                    //character #5

    FILE *filePtr;

    filePtr = fopen("rmchr.out", "w");

    if( filePtr == NULL)
      printf("Unable to open the data file.\n");

   else
    {
        print_rmchr(filePtr, str1, chr1);
        print_rmchr(filePtr, str2, chr2);
        print_rmchr(filePtr, str3, chr3);
        print_rmchr(filePtr, str4, chr4);
        print_rmchr(filePtr, str5, chr5);

        if (fclose(filePtr) != 0)
            printf("Unable to close the data file.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

//remove certain characters from array
void rmchr(char str[], char ch) {
   int i, j = 0;    //loop variable
   int size;        //lengh 
   char new_str[20];    //new array

   size = strlen(str);

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      if (str[i] != ch) {
         new_str[j] = str[i];
         j++;
      }
   }
   new_str[j] = '\0';

   strcpy(str, new_str);
}

// print array before and after editing array
void print_rmchr (char str[], char ch){

    //remove certain characters from array
    void rmchr(char str[], char ch);

    if (fprintf(filePtr, "The string '%s' will be removed from '%c' characters. \n\n", str, ch) < 0)
        printf("Unable to print non-modified string with a modifying character. \n");

    rmchr(str, ch);

    if (fprintf(filePtr, "New modified string is: '%s'. \n\n", str) < 0)
        printf("Unable to print new modified string. \n");
}

    /* In case you will need user input:
    //USER INPUT
    printf("Enter the string : \n");
    gets(str);

    printf("Enter character which you want to delete : \n");
    scanf("%ch", &ch);

    print_rmchr(str, ch);
    */
```

FINAL, corrected version:

```
/*
* A simple program to remove certain characters from the given strings                              
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 20

int main () {

    // print array before and after editing array
    void print_rmchr (FILE *filePtr, char str[], char ch);

    char str1[MAX] = "abracadabra";      //string #1
    char str2[MAX] = "abracadabra";      //string #2
    char str3[MAX] = "abracadabra";      //string #3
    char str4[MAX] = "aaaa";             //string #4
    char str5[MAX] = "aaaa";             //string #5

    char chr1 = 'a';                    //character #1
    char chr2 = 'b';                    //character #2
    char chr3 = 'n';                    //character #3
    char chr4 = 'a';                    //character #4
    char chr5 = 'n';                    //character #5

FILE *filePtr = NULL; // best to always initialize stack variables

if( NULL == (filePtr = fopen("rmchr.txt", "w") ) )
{
    // output your message, plus the system error message
    perror("fopen rmchr.out for write failed");

    // exit() and EXIT_FAILURE in 'stdlib.h'
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
}
// implied else, fopen successful

    print_rmchr(filePtr, str1, chr1);
    print_rmchr(filePtr, str2, chr2);
    print_rmchr(filePtr, str3, chr3);
    print_rmchr(filePtr, str4, chr4);
    print_rmchr(filePtr, str5, chr5);

    if (fclose(filePtr) != 0)
        printf("Unable to close the data file.\n");

    return 0;
}

//remove certain characters from array
void rmchr(char str[], char ch)
{
    size_t i;       //loop variable
    int j = 0;      //loop variable
    char new_str[MAX];    //new array

    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
      if (str[i] != ch) {
         new_str[j] = str[i];
         j++;
      }
    }
    new_str[j] = '\0';

    strcpy(str, new_str);  
}

// print array before and after editing array
print_rmchr (FILE *filePtr, char str[], char ch){

    //remove certain characters from array
    void rmchr(char str[], char ch);

    if (fprintf(filePtr, "All instances of character %c will be removed from string '%s. \n\n", ch, str) < 0)
        printf("Unable to print non-modified string with a modifying character. \n");

    rmchr(str, ch);

    if (fprintf(filePtr, "New modified string is: '%s'. \n\n", str) < 0)
        printf("Unable to print new modified string. \n");
}

    /* In case you will need user input:
    //USER INPUT
    printf("Enter the string : \n");
    fgets(str);

    printf("Enter character which you want to delete : \n");
    scanf("%ch", &ch);
    //need to check the returned value of scanf

    print_rmchr(str, ch);
    */
```

Comment: Your function `void print_rmchr (char str[], char ch)` does not take a file pointer argument, but it uses one. However it is defined in `main` so it is out of the scope of `print_rmchr`. Either pass the file pointer as an arguemnt, or move it to be a global variable (not good practice).

Comment: Also : you write `print_rmchr(filePtr, str1, chr1);`, but it takes only 2 arguments.

Comment: `void print_rmchr (char str[], char ch);` --> `void print_rmchr (FILE *filePtr, char str[], char ch);`, `void print_rmchr (char str[], char ch){` --> `void print_rmchr (FILE *filePtr ,char str[], char ch){`

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  The compiler outputs 34 messages.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )   I'm running on ubuntu linux 14.04.4 with gcc version: 4.8.4.  Strongly suggest fixing all those warnings.

Comment: While it _is_ legal to have embedded function prototypes inside a function (e.g. the `rmchr` inside `print_rmchr`, which is unnecessary since `rmchr` appears above `print_rmchr`), for this simple program it's much easier to put them at the top of the file as "forward" declarations [the "nested" declaration is _less_ usual and _more_ prone to error]. Or, just reorder the functions in the file as: `rmchr, print_rmchr, main`. Currently, you've got conflicting definitions.

Comment: 1) place function prototypes outside/before the first function.  2) Best to write a prototype for every function in the file.

Comment: all the system functions, like `fopen()` return some success/fail status. and set the hidden variable `errno`.   Statements about an error condition should be displayed on `stderr`.  When a system function returns an error indication, you have choice between using `fprintf()` or using `perror()`.   The perror() function is much easier to use but not as flexible.   After displaying an error message, it is normal to 'cleanup' (close files, free memory, etc) then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the function `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not an `int`, so the declaration of `size` should be: `size_t size;`  Note: this may require a bit of tweaking of certain other spots in the code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: comments after the code, indicate to use `gets()`,  However, `gets() has been depreciated for years and completely removed in the C11 standard.  Suggest using `fgets()`

Comment: comments after the code indicate using `scanf()`.   When ever using any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this statement: `if (fprintf(filePtr, "The string '%s' will be removed from '%c' characters. \n\n", str, ch) < 0)` is not correct.  Suggest: `if (fprintf(filePtr, "All instances of character %c will be removed from string '%s. \n\n", ch, str) < 0)`

Comment: @user3629249, the code I put in the comments are obsolete, agree. They were taken from really old book that our teacher is using for our class.

Comment: in the `rmchr()` function: the `size` variable can be eliminated, then this line: `for (i = 0; i < size; i++)` would be: `for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)`.   Then the loop would still exit correctly when it encounters the '\0' character at the end of the string.

Comment: @CraigEstey my teacher wants to do all function prototypes mostly in the main function (+ sometimes in other functions). Global function protorypes get -1 point for each. That looks very obsolete, but I have to adjust to teacher's rules. :-)

Comment: in the `rmchr()` function, 'j' will never get ahead of 'i', so the string could be modified 'inplace' rather than placed in a 'automatic' char array.   Also, when happens when the original string is more than 19 characters?  Then the 'automatic' char array could be overrun, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @user3629249 teacher doesn't like global function prototypes :-(

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: @user3629249 I appreciate your work here, but I am so complete noob! I will save in the comments of what I will have to fix later. One day I will return when I will understand C better.

Comment: @user3629249 what do you mean by magic numbers? If you are talking about str(i) and chr(i) then I guess you are correct.

Comment: global function prototypes???  all functions have file global scope.   Embedding the prototype for  function-2 inside function-1 means the compiler will use the embedded prototype within function-1  but will use what ever function-2 signature is when actually compiling function-2  I.E. those signatures can be different.   When the prototype is before any functions, then every call to function-2 and the function-2 signature are forced to be the same.  Otherwise the compiler will output a warning message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111035/discussion-between-mikhail-and-user3629249).

Comment: 'magic' numbers are numbers that have no basis.   In the posted code, the 'magic' numbers are/is: `20`

Comment: Your teacher doesn't like global function prototypes? I've got 35+ years of C programming experience and that's just plain silly [one of the silliest things I've ever heard a teacher say]. Your teacher is a **lousy** C programmer. It is quite common to autogenerate the prototypes with a script. Also, it is _necessary_ for global prototypes functions in `libc` like `fprintf`, `fopen`, etc. that are defined in `stdio.h`. Without global prototypes, you'd have to manually create scoped ones in all functions that use a given function. Your teacher would get fired from any commercial programming job

Comment: @CraigEstey, many younger teachers that I have met use global function prototypes. My teacher is like 70+ years old, don't blame her. :-) The book that we use in class doesn't come with a CD disk. It comes with *diskette* instead. I guess the issue comes from a book.  It's literally older than me. :-)

Comment: I'm 61 and started C in 1981, there were no ANSI protos then, but I started using them ASAP because they were better [25+ years ago]. From your teacher: No globals. So no printf proto in stdio.h? Can't do your own at top of your .c? So, _every_ fnc you write has to have a fnc scoped proto? Seriously, think about it. She's teaching you out of date stuff (e.g. `+=` was originally `=+` but nobody's used that since 1980). As an academician, it is part of your teacher's job to continue her own education, to be able to teach the language as it is commonly used now

Comment: When I started in 1972, I was using Fortran IV--nothing like Fortran of today. I also started with keypunch cards, but not after 1977. At each stage, when new tech came along, (e.g. mainframe, mini, supermini, micro, workstation) or new languages (or improvements), it has been part of my job to learn and adapt. I'll [still] fault your teacher for not figuring out the logic/sensibility/rationale of the global protos and changing her view [_and_ the book :-)] over a **25** year period. She could at least use a mimeograph handout to explain the global protos. In the end, she's only hurting _you_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to pass more or other arguments to a function, you must modify both the calls and the function definition, so that they are compatible with each other. Change it from

```
void print_rmchr (char str[], char ch);
```

to:

```
void print_rmchr (FILE *filePtr, char str[], char ch);
```

As is, the symbol `filePtr` is local to `main` and not known in `print_rmchr`.

Comment: It works! Yeah, I supposed to do that. Next time will be more careful.
One more question: for **filePtr = fopen("rmchr.txt", "w");**. When I run the program, and the file doesn't exist, it just created one. Isn't the 'w' supposed to yell when the file is not found instead of creating one?

Comment: No. The `"w"` will create a new file when it doesn't exist and it will overwrite an existing file if a file with the given name already exists.

Answer (score 0):

after applying all the comments, the `rmchr()` function becomes:

```
//remove certain characters from array
void rmchr(char str[], char ch)
{
   size_t i;
   int    j = 0;    //loop variable

   for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)
   {
      if (str[i] != ch)
      {
         new_str[j] = str[i];
         j++;
      }
   }

   str[j] = '\0';
}
```

When opening a file, this pattern will give you problems, mostly due to the extranious indenting of any following code:

```
FILE *filePtr;

filePtr = fopen("rmchr.out", "w");

if( filePtr == NULL)
  printf("Unable to open the data file.\n");

else


suggest using the following pattern:

FILE *filePtr = NULL; // best to always initialize stack variables

if( NULL == (filePtr = fopen("rmchr.out", "w") ) )
{
    // output your message, plus the system error message
    perror( "fopen rmchr.out for write failed" );

    // exit() and EXIT_FAILURE in 'stdlib.h'
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );  
}

// implied else, fopen successful
```